# Python Parse module Error when doing Query.filter or Query.get

Tags: python, parse-platform

Using www.parse.com and following instructions:

https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy

Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39)

I created a class called testClass

```
class testClass(Object):
    """Create a Test Class Object"""
    testId = ''
    def __init__(self,param):
        logging.info("testClass() New testClass object created()")
        print 'testClass() New testClass object created()'
        self.testId = param
```

I can create new Objects in Parse by using:

```
def testClassFromParse(param):
    try:
        testObj = testClass(param)
        testObj.save()
        hello = testClass.Query.filter(objectId='TQysq4uOp6')
        print type(hello)
        print hello
    except Exception,e:
        print traceback.format_exc()
        print 'testClassFromParse() Error'
```

Every time I executed, my new row is created in Parse Dashboard succesfully, but when I want to retrieve the Object using either testId or objectId based on example, I get:

```
testClass() New testClass object created()
<class 'parse_rest.query.Queryset'>


File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/parse_rest/query.py", line 58, in get
    return self.filter(**kw).get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/parse_rest/query.py", line 142, in get
    results = self._fetch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/parse_rest/query.py", line 117, in _fetch
    return self._manager._fetch(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/parse_rest/query.py", line 41, in _fetch
    return [klass(**it) for it in klass.GET(uri, **kw).get('results')]
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'objectId'

testClassFromParse() Error
```

I can confirm that via my Dashboard objectId exists.
Also tried with a different property: testID, but same results.

Any ideas, how to retrieve object and then access its elements?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you defined an `__init__` method for the `testClass Object` that replaces the built-in one. As described in the [documentation](https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy), a Parse object should be created as something like:

```
class GameScore(Object):
    pass
```

You are welcome to add extra, application-specific methods to your class, but if you replace the `__init__` method (as you did with `__init__(self, param)`), the Object can no longer be built when it gets a value back from Parse.

The right way to set `testId` in your class is to provide it as a named argument:

```
class testClass(Object):
    pass

testObj = testClass(testId=param)
```

---

Now, let's say you actually do want some behavior upon initialization of your class: for instance, in your `__init__` you required that `testId` be provided, and you had it log a message each time the object is created. You can do this by writing an `__init__` method and then calling the super class's `__init__` method when you're done:

```
class testClass(Object):
    """Create a Test Class Object"""
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        logging.info("testClass() New testClass object created()")
        print 'testClass() New testClass object created()'

        assert "testId" in kwargs

        Object.__init__(self, **kwargs)
```